# not using a good "practice" to pull calendar dates on to a spreadsheet- should I save to array, and then write array to the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

running firefox 23.0.1 on a windows 7 box

I am trying to import a long list of dates (1,000-2,000) from my calendar to a spreadsheet.  It was working great, until I started adding all my student lesson meetings.  Now it seems to work but I am getting time-out messages, and it takes forever.

there is a separate sheet that only keeps track of the A1:student name, B1:location, and C:1 Start time

```
function calpull(){
  //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendar.html#getEvents
  // The code below will retrieve events between 2 dates for the user's default         calendar and
  // display the events the current spreadsheet
     var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
     var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("August 15,2013"), new Date("January 15, 2014"));

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
     var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(),     events[i].getStartTime(),]];
   // the +3 makes the data start on the third row, protecting the first two rows
     var row=i+3;
      //for some unknown reason, I have to set the active sheet here
     var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1].getRange(row,1,1,3);
    range.setValues(details);
  }
}
```

My question is that I think it reads every event individually, and places it on a row.  I am trying to figure out how to save all the data I want to an array, and then save the array to the spreadsheet all at once.

my last script attempt looks like this, but does not work:

```
function calpull(){
  //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendar.html#getEvents
  // The code below will retrieve events between 2 dates for the user's default calendar and
  // display the events the current spreadsheet
     var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
     var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("August 15,2013"), new Date("August 15, 2014"));

for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    //http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/class_calendarevent.html
     var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(),                 events[i].getStartTime(),]];
   // the +3 makes the data start on the third row, protecting the first two rows
     var row=i+3;
      //for some unknown reason, I have to set the active sheet here
     var range=ss.getRange(row,1,1,3);
    range.setValues(details);
  }
}
```

My question is that I think it reads every event individually, and places it on a row.  I am trying to figure out how to save all the data I want to an array, and then save the array to the spreadsheet all at once.

Very much a noob question, I seem to always be missing on some basic information. That everyone assumes that I would know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to do it using an array :

1 - Get data from Calendar :

```
  var Calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('calendar_name');
  var events = Calendar[0].getEvents(startDate , endDate, {max: 4000});// this option to ensure that you get more than the default 1000 events
  if (events[0]){
    var eventArray = new Array();// this array will hold the whole sheet data
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var line = new Array();// this array will hold data for each row
      FUS1=events[i].getStartTime().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";// this variable is used to take care of daylight savings parameter of each event to prevent time errors on long periods of time
      var title = events[i].getTitle()
      line.push(title);
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy")+' à ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      line.push(Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "dd-MM-yyyy")+' à ' +Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(), FUS1, "HH:mm"));
      line.push(events[i].getLocation());
      line.push(' -- ');// this can be removed, it simply adds a column with "--"
      line.push(((events[i].getEndTime() - events[i].getStartTime())/ 3600000).toString().replace('.',','));
      line.push(' ')
      eventArray.push(line);
    }
  }
```

2 - write array to sheet (and format column with on the fly.... but this is purely optional):

```
  sheet.getRange(1,1,eventArray.length,eventArray[0].length).setValues(eventArray);
  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 450).setColumnWidth(2, 150).setColumnWidth(3, 150).setColumnWidth(4, 250).setColumnWidth(5, 120).setColumnWidth(6, 75).setColumnWidth(7, 450);
```

Comment: wow, just saw the post, and I am trying to get it to work.  There are a lot of functions I have not seen before so I will spend some time figuring it out too.

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of undefined. (line 3, file "Code")  I even changed the .getCalendarByName, to .getDefultCalendar and no go.  I wonder why it is not defining the dataset

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for clarification where needed.

Comment: That worked great, once I had a good night sleep and could think clearly, and I could look up the substr() command!  I needed to change some formats to make it work with my other code, but it is great!  thank you a bunch